# How to deal with multiple include in different php file?

Tags: php

I want to send a message over WhatsApp from a php file. I've already discovered the library which let do it and it works in this way:

```
<?php
include_once './src/whatsprot.class.php';

function send($target,$message){
$username = "phone";
$password = "password";
$w = new WhatsProt($username,"Nickname", true); //Name your application by replacing “WhatsApp Messaging”
$w->connect();
$w->loginWithPassword($password);

$w->SendPresenceSubscription($target); //Let us first send presence to user
$w->sendMessage($target,$message ); // Send Message
}

send("phone","Text of the message");
```

?>

If I try to execute this or launch it via a php web server it works. If I try to call the method `send($target,$message);` from another php file, like this, it doesn't work:

```
 <?php 

include "whatsapp.php";

send($target, $message);

?>
```

What's the problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I try to call the method `send($target,$message);` from another php file, it doesn't work
>   What's the problem?

Most probably another php file is located in a different directory and this command doesn't work:

```
include_once './src/whatsprot.class.php';
```

Try to use an absolute path to file.